# "Master" Wordpress Multisite - Database Sync

Tags: plugins, multisite, database, get-plugin-data

I've had an idea in my head about creating a Wordpress Multisite environment that would have Plugins along with them that would not only have "default" settings, but be able to update each blog's plugin options based on a "master" site. That way, instead of having to change settings through every site - you'd be able to just change it in one spot.

Now I've seen http://snippets.davejamesmiller.com/code/php/wordpress/automatically-enable-plugins-in-new-wordpress-multisite-blogs which can handle activating and setting specific plugin settings - but this wouldn't take care of any ongoing sync between the websites. There'd be times when certain settings shouldn't be brought over/synced, for things like an API key for Akismet for example. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, you will have to loop over all the blogs and set the plugin option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-multisite-mirror/
or
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/yd-wpmu-sitewide-options/

Comment: Thanks! - Looks like YD WPMU Sitewide Options may be a good fit moving forward.